# Issue compiling opencv in osx maverick: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake

Today I have upgrade from osx 10.8 to 10.9, now I'm trying to compile opencv master from github but I have some issues

```
[ 21%] Built target IlmImf
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___sincos_stret", referenced from:
      cv::RotatedRect::points(cv::Point_<float>*) const in matrix.cpp.o
      cv::RotatedRect::boundingRect() const in matrix.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Can anyone give me an hand?

Comment: The title is not the place to put your Google Search.  It is the place to put a brief summary of your question.

Comment: i have edited titl....ok?

Comment: See my update to your title.  Note that English has capital letters; make sure you're using the shift key properly on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update to Xcode 5.0.1 through the App Store and download the Command-line Tools for Mavericks from the developer site: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action.
Finally, make sure you clean up your cmake cache.

Answer (score 1):

Use g++ to compile your c++ code instead of gcc. This actually solved my similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the `-mmacosx-version-min=10.8` option when compiling with g++. It might not be a permanent solution, but at least my code compiles again.

Comment: Please try to avoid posting [exact duplicate answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19662430/474189). If you think the question is a duplicate (which it seems to be), flag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I met the above error too.
After I install the command line tool and cmake and make again, above error disappears.